# Why does the if statement at line 18 not prevent the error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, cryptography

I am writing a program for a substitution cipher and I am curious why I am getting list index out range at line 20 if i am passing 0 to x if it surpasses the len of array key1

```
import string
import random


alphabet= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
file1 = open("MyFile.txt","r")
dict1 = {}
key1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,7]
key = 4
plain_txt= file1.read()
file1.close()
x = 0
cipher = []


for char in plain_txt:
    c = alphabet.find(char)
    if x > len(key1):
        x = 0
    c = c + key1[x]
    if c > 25:
       c = 0
    char  = alphabet[c]
    cipher.append(char)
    x +=1

cipher = "".join(cipher)
print(cipher)
```

Comment: `x==len(key1)` will be outside the array. Therefore you need `>=`, not `>`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. my output is not what I expected but that's a different issue.